# Transformation of homogeneous coordinates to Euclidean coordinates?

Tags: vectors, coordinate-systems, transformation, homogeneous-spaces

I understand that two vectors

$$
v_{1} = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}
\quad
\text{,}
\quad
v_{2} = \begin{pmatrix} x' \\ y' \\ z' \end{pmatrix}
$$

in homogeneous coordinates are equivalent if

$$
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}
=
\lambda
\begin{pmatrix} x' \\ y' \\ z' \end{pmatrix}
\quad,\quad
\lambda \neq 0.
$$

I visualize these equivalence classes as "rays" from the coordinate system origin (with the origin itself excluded).

To convert a vector from homogeneous to Euclidean coordinates, one divides all components by a number such that $z\rightarrow 1$. Example:

$$
\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 8 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}_\text{hom}
\quad
\rightarrow
\quad
\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 4 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}_\text{eucl}
$$

Question: What is the correct transformation of $v = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}_\text{hom}$ to Euclidean coordinates?

UPDATE - I'm adding the [source](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kyros/courses/418/Lectures/lecture.2010f.02.pdf) for this question. This is the slide in question:

[image: slide]

Take a look at how $P _{4} \,$ and $P _{5} \,$ are transformed:

$$
P_{4, \,hom} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0.0001 \end{pmatrix}
\quad
\rightarrow
\quad
P_{4, \,eucl} = \begin{pmatrix} 10000 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
P_{5, \,hom} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
\quad
\rightarrow
\quad
\text{"at infinity} \,\textbf{on x-axis}"
$$

Comment: SE seems to have problems displaying MathJax code (I used https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) - what's that matter?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). In short, questions here are not purely $\LaTeX$, and so you must add delimiters (`$`) indicate where MathJax sections begin and end.

Comment: @Brian: Sorry, missed the dollar signs. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$v$ is a point at infinity. There is no equivalent point in euclidean space, but you can think it as the point of intersection of the lines of a parallel bundle.

Comment: What is a parallel bundle and how are parallel lines supposed to intersect?

Comment: A bundle (or maybe better sheaf) of lines is the set of all the lines passing through a point. This bundle is defined improper when the lines are parallel, so that they never intersect in the euclidean plane. Now, take the bundle of lines defined by $y=k$. We can think that two lines get close as $x$ becomes large, just like the railtracks seem to get close due to the perspective. If we take the point $(x, k)$ and its homogeneous equivalent $(x, k, 1)$ and "normalize" it for $x\to \infty$ we have the coordinates $(1, 0, 0)$ of the intersection point of the bundle.

Comment: Just to be sure, by $y=k \,$ do you mean the bundle of lines intersecting at the point $(0,k)$? And is $k \,$ to be taken as a parameter, i.e. are we looking at a sheaf of bundles all intersecting on the $y$-Axis? Also, the question was how to transform $(1,0,0)_{hom}$ from homogeneous to Euklidean coordinates...this wasn't clear in the question (edited it)

Comment: By $y=k$ I mean the bundle of lines parallel to the x axis. They don't intersect on the euclidean plane but they intersect in the homogeneus space in the homogeneus point that you named $v$ in your question. As I wrote in my answer, you cannot transform it in euclidean coordinates as it does not exist as a poin on the plane.

Comment: Thanks, I don't quite understand how parallels can intersect (is this somehow related to the parallel axiom?), but I think I've understood the answer. I've added a lecture slide to make it clear